# Uninstall Manjaro installation

Tags: manjaro, uninstall

I am facing a grub issue, an error mentionning `calloc`, I didn't pay much attention

After a lot of troubleshooting, grub was never able to find my Windows 10 installation, so I gave up on that part (some MRB/GPT incompatibility between my two partitions)

Also, I don't boot that much in my Manjaro anymore, so I am considering uninstalling it, reclaiming some storage space in the process

If I just format the partition, I will likely break something, as I have a separate partition for `/boot`

How do I safely uninstall my Manjaro, getting back the storage from the `/` partition and the `/boot` partition?

Comment: What's the configuration you want? If you don't need the information in any Non-windows partition, you could prolly use the Windows partition manager to erase it and add it to whatever partition it's near to.

Comment: I want to clear the manjaro partition, and merge the partition with my windows

Comment: Can you boot into Windows at all? You might need to do this: https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-mbr/ . The get into the Windows disk editor, and erase the Linux partitions.

Comment: my windows is fine if I select its drive on powering on the computer